# Post image from Windows Phone Application to PHP

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, encoding, base64

I am trying to develop an application for Windows Phone 7 which uploads a selected picture (from the picture chooser task) to a server with the use of PHP.

I am trying to use HttpWebRequest in order to do this. And the data is posted successfully too.
The Problem that I am facing is that the image is required to be encoded to base64 before posting.
And, I am not able to encode it properly.

This is my C# code so far:

```
public partial class SamplePage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public SamplePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        PhotoChooserTask selectphoto = null;

        private void SampleBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            selectphoto = new PhotoChooserTask();
            selectphoto.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(selectphoto_Completed);
            selectphoto.Show();
        }

        void selectphoto_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
        {
            if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
            {
                BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(e.ChosenPhoto);
                image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(e.OriginalFileName));
                txtBX.Text = e.OriginalFileName;

                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://"+QR_Reader.MainPage.txtBlck+"/beamer/saveimage.php");
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                string str = BitmapToByte(image1);
                MessageBox.Show(str);

                string postData = String.Format("image={0}", str);   

                // Getting the request stream.
                request.BeginGetRequestStream
                (result =>
                {
                    // Sending the request.
                    using (var requestStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(result))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
                        {
                            writer.Write(postData);
                            writer.Flush();
                        }
                    }

                    // Getting the response.
                    request.BeginGetResponse(responseResult =>
                    {
                        var webResponse = request.EndGetResponse(responseResult);
                        using (var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                        {
                            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                            {
                                string srresult = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                            }
                        }
                    }, null);
                }, null);

            }  // end of taskresult == OK           
        }  // end of select photo completed

        private Stream ImageToStream(Image image1)
        {
            WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(400, 400);

            wb.Render(image1, new TranslateTransform { X = 400, Y = 400 });

            wb.Invalidate();
            Stream myStream = new MemoryStream();

            wb.SaveJpeg(myStream, 400, 400, 0, 70);

            return myStream;
        }
        private string BitmapToByte(Image image) //I suspect there is something wrong here
        {
            Stream photoStream = ImageToStream(image);
            BitmapImage bimg = new BitmapImage();
            bimg.SetSource(photoStream); //photoStream is a stream containing data for a photo

            byte[] bytearray = null;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                 WriteableBitmap wbitmp = new WriteableBitmap(bimg);
                 wbitmp.SaveJpeg(ms, wbitmp.PixelWidth, wbitmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
                 bytearray = ms.ToArray();
            }
            string str = Convert.ToBase64String(bytearray);
            return str;
        }
    }
```

The BitmapToByte function is used to convert the image to base64 string.
And, the ImageToStream function is used to convert it to stream.

Now, I seriously suspect that there is something wrong in these two functions.

Further, I'm getting exactly the same base64 string for every image. Yes, I'm getting exactly same base64 string irrespective of what image I'm selecting. This is very weird.
I don't know what is wrong with this.

I've uploaded a text file here: http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=vWZy
It contains that base64 string.

On, the server side, the PHP is accepting the postdata successfully and the decoding is working perfectly too (I decoded some base64 strings manually to ensure this).
Only problem I'm facing is base64 encoding.

Please help me.

**EDIT**
I've made the following changes in the ImageToStream and BitmapToByte functions:

```
private MemoryStream ImageToStream(Image image1)
        {
            WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(400, 400);

            wb.Render(image1, new TranslateTransform { X = 400, Y = 400 });

            wb.Invalidate();
            MemoryStream myStream = new MemoryStream();

            wb.SaveJpeg(myStream, 400, 400, 0, 70);

            return myStream;
        }

        private string BitmapToByte(Image image)
        {
            MemoryStream photoStream = ImageToStream(image);

            byte[] bytearray = photoStream.ToArray();
            string str = Convert.ToBase64String(bytearray);
            return str;
        }
```

Comment: If there are any alternate approaches for uploading an image to PHP, then they are fine too.
All, I want to do is to **upload** my image, that's it.

Comment: Please edit your code to include only the parts relevant to the question.

Comment: Using WebClient.UploadFile maybe it's more simple than httpwebrequest since webclient it is a wrapper of httpwebrequest http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144229.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You BitmapToByte method is tremendously overcomplicated. Change `ImageToStream` to return a `MemoryStream` and:

```
private string BitmapToByte(Image image)
{
    MemoryStream photoStream = ImageToStream(image);

    byte[] bytearray = photoStream.ToArray();
    string str = Convert.ToBase64String(bytearray);
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Okay. I'll try this. But, can you help me to simplify the ImageToStream function?

Comment: I'm not actually very familiar with Windows Phone, but from what I can tell, your `ImageToStream` method is pretty good for that platform.

Comment: I'm sorry for such a late reply, actually my PC got crashed and took this long to recover.

So, I tried your code for the BitmapToByte function but I am still getting the same incorrect ouput for every file.

Check my edited post to see the changes that I've made.
This is for my University Project and I don't have much time left, so please help me.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know enough to do much more without testing things myself, and I don't have a WP7 dev environment set up. I can ask a few more questions though. Are you sure that `image` is a valid image in the first place? Is the output now the same as the output in the text file you posted before? Finally, should you be calling `Measure` and `Arrange` (as noted in the Remarks section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.render%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)?

Comment: @Shrayansh Another note about your base64 string. It's clearly trying to be a jpeg file. Converting it to binary and looking at it in a hex editor shows that the file starts out fine, but it seems to become corrupted somewhere along the way. There are a couple interesting patterns. The ascii character string "456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz" for example, seems oddly specific, and the last 2.5k bytes of the file are just the same eight byte sequence repeated over and over. Do you have anyone at your university that might be able to help you with the details of the jpeg format?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

`image` is a valid image, yes.
Yes, the output is still the image as the previous one.

Comment: And, I've found a great alternative to upload files. I'm now using RestSharp Library to upload pictures and it is working great!

Thanks a lot for all the help, anyway.